# I'm having a problem with Ionic styles not working properly in my Next.js application

Tags: ionic-framework, next.js

I am facing an issue where Ionic styles are not being applied to some pages in my Next.js application. Specifically, the Ionic styles are working on the home page but not on the profile page. I am seeking guidance on how to troubleshoot and ensure that Ionic styles are properly applied to both pages.

Here is the code and file structure

```
page.tsx in the src/app folder:

export default function Home() {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    return router.push('/home');
  }, []);

  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
      {/* Ionic components */}
      <IonButton color="primary">
        Previous
      </IonButton>
    </main>
  );
}
```

```
src/app/layout.tsx in the src/app folder:

import './globals.scss'
/* Core CSS required for Ionic components to work properly */
import '@ionic/react/css/core.css';

// /* Basic CSS for apps built with Ionic */
import '@ionic/react/css/normalize.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/typography.css';

// /* Optional CSS utils that can be commented out */
import '@ionic/react/css/padding.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/float-elements.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/text-alignment.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/text-transformation.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/flex-utils.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/display.css';

import Script from 'next/script';

import { Inter } from 'next/font/google';

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export default function RootLayout ({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
      <Script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.esm.js"></Script>
      </head>
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

```
src/app/Profile/Profile.tsx

import {IonButton} from "@ionic/react"
export default function Profile() {
  return (
      <IonButton color="primary">
        Profile Button
      </IonButton>
  );
}
```

here in profile page the ionic style on IonButton is not working

I expected that by systematically checking these aspects and comparing the "Home" and "Profile" pages, I would be able to identify the root cause of the issue preventing Ionic styles from being applied consistently.

Answer (score 0):

Rename `Profile.tsx` to `page.tsx`. By default, Next.js renders every page as a server component. The `@ionic/react` library works as client-side. Need "use client" directive to render as client-side.

```
export default function ProfilePage() {
    return <ProfileComponent/>
}
```

And please name your page and component carefully because it's confusing.

Comment: I tried that as well but it did't work

Comment: After you said it didn't work, I tried and solved the problem. Also, I think the `@ionic/react` library is not to be integrated with next.js.

Comment: Here is the repo: https://github.com/golamrabbiazad/ionic-nextjs-app

Answer (score 0):

just use Ionic CDN, place it in the layout.tsx file , under your app/page folder

```
 <script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.esm.js"></script>

    <script nomodule src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.js"></script>
 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/css/ionic.bundle.css" />
```